# Min-height and absolute positioning

Tags: css

I'm developing a mobile website that integrates horizontal swiping. Unfortunately this has created a headache when trying to get the rest of my website layout to work.

http://jsfiddle.net/N7eWS/4/ - try resizing your browser window fairly small and you'll see the #footer (red) halfway down the content inside #wrapper (green). This appears to be todo with setting height:100% on most of the elements and then the absolute positioning applied to the horizontal swiping div (swipeview-masterpage-1).

I want it so that #wrapper expands to the height of the content, the #footer sits underneath #wrapper and is always off the bottom of the screen (you should have to scroll to see it).

Is there anyway I can make this work without touching (or perhaps making minor changes to) the swipeview divs? Any ideas would be appreciated!

Comment: tried everything, nothing worked. I would like to know the answer too =)

Comment: does #swipeview-masterpage-1 <em>have</em> to be absolutely positioned?

Comment: Unfortunately I believe so - it's the div that moves horizontally when you swipe

Comment: Well, since absolutely positioned elements are removed from the layout, they do not affect its parent's height/width. So one way is to put the footer inside the #swipeview-master-1 div... how does that work for you? http://jsfiddle.net/jklm313/N7eWS/5/

Comment: Completely makes sense now you've said that - it's really obvious :( Unfortunately putting the footer inside the swipeview div wouldn't really work - it means the footer would get swiped along with the content! The only solution I can think of is to use JavaScript to get the height of the contents and then set #wrapper to that height..

Answer (score 0):

One of the problems is the `position: absolute` on `#swipeview-masterpage-1` and then another `absolute` on the parent. Parent absolute elements will not expand to the height of any absolutely positioned children ([example](http://jsfiddle.net/YUdHA/1/)).

You also have a random `<span>` in the mix, which is an inline element and will have a height of 0 anyway. Remove that to make things clearer.

Now to why your footer is appearing in a strange way. Your `#wrapper` will always be 100% of the parent height, your footer will always exist at 100px (header) + 100%. Disable the `min-height` property and you will see the wrapper collapse, and the footer sit at 100px. That's why the `#wrapper` content overlaps the footer.